# circuit triggers with bad voltage 0.05v

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis

the below circuit triggers with 0.05 volt, even if touched the base of 2N3906 the circuit triggers ,
what is the issue or alteration to be done to fix the circuit to work only at 0.5volt or higher is applied on the signal pin.[image]

Comment: applied 12volt 1Amps

Comment: how to update this circuit with the new suggestions , so that i can go with production with the design with minimal alteration.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the issue or alteration to be done to fix the circuit to work only at 0.5volt or higher is applied on the signal pin

A overall more sensible topology for what you are trying to achieve.  The PNP front end references its input to the 12 V supply. Setting it up to threshold at 500 mV is going to be tricky since that really means 11.5 V from the transistor's point of view.  A 10% error in that threshold changes it by over 1 volt.

Either use a comparator, or at least a NPN front end.  If you can live with 600-700 mV or so threshold, then you can use the B-E junction in the transistor as the comparator.

You may also need to invert the logic, depending on what you intend to "work" when the input signal is above 500 mV.

Comment: so you mean to wire like this , http://www.mayothi.com/images/transistor3.gif

Comment: @cc4: At least the NPN front end.  The LED differs from the FET you are trying to drive, which is then trying to drive your load.

Comment: @cc4re That circuit (in the link) works with lrelatively low load currents (like the pictured LED). For a 12V1A load, you'll need a slightly more complex topology & will probably want to stick with your power MOSFET as the load-switching transistor.

Answer (score 2):

Using a PNP transistor for your first stage means that the lower the voltage on your signal trace, the higher the current of the 12V potential that can back-feed your signal path through the PNP transistor's base & the 1K series resistor, so the higher the trans-conductancs of the transistor. (in short, the circuit as drawn is triggered by voltage on signal 'going low').

If, as you stated in your written description, you want your circuit to 'trigger' when your signal pin 'goes high,' you'll want to use an NPN type transistor instead.

If you can 'be happy' with an 0.7V 'threshold' for your circuit to 'trigger', then something like this could work:
[image]

If, however, you actually need the circuit to trigger reliably @ 0.05V, then you'll need to add an amplifier before this circuit, in order to raise your signal to the NPN transistor's requisite 0.7V.

Comment: what are the resistor values

Comment: @cc4re I didn't read the full datasheets & calculate those values, but you can calculate the resistor values you will need based on the B-E and C-E currents you choose to drive through the NPN transistors.